# Android Anko alert with custom view error (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, anko

I want to create an alert dialog with custom elements using anko.

Every guide and tutorial I've found uses this method:

```
alert {
    customView {
        textView("Hello")
    }
}.show()
```

But I get an error in `customView` saying:

```
Error:(73, 13) Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline fun <reified T : View> Activity.customView(theme: Int = ..., init: T.() -> Unit): T
Please specify it explicitly.
```

Has something changed in Anko and has not being documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick the second item that Android Studio suggests you -

> 'customView for AlertBuilder<*> in org.jetbrains.anko'

[image]